# How could Juliana have travelled to our world?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

Just yesterday I completed watching season 4 of *The Man in the High Castle* and had a burning question throughout the entire season.

It could be a plot hole, or it could be I missed some vital clue.

At the end of season 3 Juliana manages to travel to 'our' world just as Smith shoots her.
But minutes before that cliffhanger scene, we also learned through Abendsen that one can only travel between worlds if your counterpart in the other world is dead.

But Juliana in our world isn't dead.
Juliana in our world is married to Tagomi's son and they have a child (season 2, episode 5)

How could Juliana have travelled to our world?

Comment: I would have to watch again to see if there was any dialogue that might of explained it, but there are only 3 possible answers. 1. The alternate Juliana did die. 2. The reality/universe wasn't the exact same one from season 2. 3. As Hawthorne had hinted at, perhaps she does not have to follow the same rules as everyone else.

Comment: @DarthLocke the Juliana in the S4 world died in a car crash with her parents.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica Cool---I could not remember what was said, but that explains it! You might want to include that in your answer (maybe a situation too, if you can find one), because that helps clarify the possibility for it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious answer is that the world in Season 2 (A) is different to the world in Season 4 (B), and neither may be ours.

Juliana-A is, as you say, alive and married to Tagomi Jr, while Juliana-B died in a car cash with her parents.

There are numerous, possibly infinite, alternate worlds.

Comment: I have accepted this answer, as I recall a dialogue in which it was stated that J died in a car crash with her family at a young age. I do find it 'suspect' that the circumstances in both alt-worlds seem to overlap a lot.

Comment: Here's an example of 'suspect'; if there are indeed numerous alt-worlds, how was John Smith able to pick the one that Juliana traveled to?

Answer (score 6):

Showrunner David Scarpa elaborated it more where she landed more:

> “She’s basically traveled to a place where the United States has won world War II,” co-showrunner David Scarpa told the audience. “She can never be herself in that [alternate] world. Her identity is tethered to that much darker world of the High Castle.” He suggested Juliana will find a way back to the dystopian reality where Germany and Japan have divided up the United States, with the goal of “saving it.” - [deadline](https://deadline.com/2019/11/the-man-in-the-high-castle-season-4-final-season-rufus-sewell-alexa-davalos-david-scarpa-isa-dick-hackett-vulture-festival-la-amazon-1202782561/)

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question

Comment: The linked source doesn't explain how Juliana could have travelled to our world.